# Replacing a character in a string with a string in Haskell in point-free style

Tags: haskell, pointfree

The idea is to write a function replace that takes three arguments, a wildcard, a substitution string, and an input string. An example would look like `replace '*' "foo" "foo*" = "foobar"`. Normally this wouldn't be too much of an issue, I'd just write something recursive and check if each character in the string equals my wildcard character. However, I need to write it in point-free style. I have no idea how to do this. I know I can drop the very last argument, the input string, but after that I'm stuck.

My non-point-free style solution is:
`replace wildcard sub = concatMap (\c -> if c==wildcard then sub else [c])` .

Note: We are not allowed to import external libaries, i.e. no Text.Replace.

Comment: Are you aware of [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io)?

Comment: Why do you need to write this in point-free style? I'm having trouble imagining any such remotely readable definition for `replace`. (Even the unreadable one requires you to import `Data.Bool` to get access to the `bool` function you need to replace the `if` expression.)

Comment: I believe you have an error in your example: `replace '*' "foo" "foo*"` should produce `"foofoo"` if I understand your description, not `"foobar"`. The latter is impossible unless it just always uses `"bar"` as the replacement value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, writing point-free just for the sake of being point-free is stupid.

The reason why it's useful to consider point-free style is that it leads, if done properly, towards a more category-compositional way of thinking. So if we want to give a *useful* answer to such a task, this is what we should keep in mind.

`concatMap` is a nice hook into a category, because it's just `>>=` in the list monad. IOW, it lifts a list-Kleisli-arrow `A->[B]` into a list-to-list function `[A]->[B]`. So let's focus on how to write

```
useChar :: Char -> [Char]
useChar = \c -> if c==wildcard then sub else [c]
```

as an arrow. I'll actually write it as a function, but you could also go into the Kleisli category instead.

First thing to note is that you're copying `c`. That's in general done with the *fanout operator*

```
(&&&) :: Arrow (~>)
   => (b~>x) -> (b~>y) -> (b~>(x,y))
```

so

```
import Control.Arrow
sub = "SUBST"
useChar = (==wildcard)&&&(:[])
       >>> \(decision, embd) -> if decision then sub else embd
```

Note, `(:[])` is the identity Kleisli arrow for the list monad; I'm not going to exploit that though.

Now, the `if` decision works on booleans, but booleans are [ugly](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/). Categorically speaking, a boolean is just a sum type of two unit types

```
 Bool ≈ Either () () ≡ (()+())
(≡≡) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Either () ()
x ≡≡ y
 | x==y       = Right ()
 | otherwise  = Left ()
```

We could as well encode some *useful* information into either of those `()` options, and specifically for the `Right` option that's clearly just the constant `sub`.

```
constRight :: c -> Bool -> Either () c
constRight _ False = Left ()
constRight c True = Right c

useChar = ((==wildcard)>>>constRight sub) &&& (:[])
       >>> \(decision, embd) -> case decision of
              Left () -> embd
              Right theSub -> theSub
```

or in a more general view

```
substRight :: c -> Either a b -> Either a c
substRight _ (Left a) = Left a
substRight c (Right _) = Right c

useChar = ((≡≡wildcard)>>>substRight sub) &&& (:[])
       >>> \(decision, embd) -> case decision of
              Left () -> embd
              Right theSub -> theSub
```

Obviously we can substitute on the left as well as a generic operator

```
useChar = ((≡≡wildcard)>>>substRight sub) &&& (:[])
       >>> \(decision, embd) -> substLeft embd decision
```

Now if we turn the tuple around the lambda is adapting to the curryed form of `substLeft`:

```
useChar = (:[]) &&& ((≡≡wildcard)>>>substRight sub) >>> uncurry substLeft
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you have written cannot be reduced with only the `Prelude`, because there is no way to reduce the `if` statement. (Erich points out that this can be done with `bool` from `Data.Bool`.) Here, I devise an alternative treatment that can be reduced, but I hope that by the end I have convinced you not to do so.

A function that you may find helpful here is `break`. From [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break):

> applied to a predicate p and a list xs, returns a tuple where first element is longest prefix (possibly empty) of xs of elements that do not satisfy p and second element is the remainder of the list

Thus we can construct a function to split your list at a particular element:

```
splitOnChar :: Char -> String -> (String, String)
splitOnChar char = break (char ==)
```

From there we can work out a function to do as you describe:

```
replaceChar :: Char -> String -> String -> String
replaceChar char repstr instr =
  case break (char ==) instr of
    (front, _:back) -> front ++ repstr ++ back
    _               -> error "Character to replace not found!"
```

This allows you to get rid of the `if` statement which is impossible to write point-free. Why on earth you would want to write this point free is beyond me, but to do so, we need to sacrifice our error handling. Let's look at the version that discards handling

```
replaceChar :: Char -> String -> String -> String
replaceChar char repstr instr =
  let ~(front, _:back) = break (char ==) instr
  in  front ++ repstr ++ back
```

Then we can replace `front` and `back` with expressions:

```
replaceChar :: Char -> String -> String -> String
replaceChar char repstr instr =
  let split = break (char ==) instr
  in  (fst split) ++ repstr ++ (tail $ snd split)
```

Now let us move `split` to the end of the `in` statement:

```
replaceChar :: Char -> String -> String -> String
replaceChar char repstr instr =
  let split = break (char ==) instr
  in  (\a b -> a ++ repstr ++ b) <$> fst <*> tail . snd $ split
```

Now we can substitute `split`:

```
replaceChar :: Char -> String -> String -> String
replaceChar char repstr instr =
  (\a b -> a ++ repstr ++ b) <$> fst <*> tail . snd $ break (char ==) instr
```

Next let us eta-reduce `b` from our lambda expression:

```
replaceChar :: Char -> String -> String -> String
replaceChar char repstr instr =
  (\a -> ((a ++ repstr) ++)) <$> fst <*> tail . snd $ break (char ==) instr
```

Then do the same with `a`:

```
replaceChar :: Char -> String -> String -> String
replaceChar char repstr instr =
  ((. (repstr ++)) . (++)) <$> fst <*> tail . snd $ break (char ==) instr
```

Then replace `instr`:

```
replaceChar :: Char -> String -> String -> String
replaceChar char repstr =
  (((. (repstr ++)) . (++)) <$> fst <*> tail . snd) . break (char ==)
```

It's easier to reduce `char` next, so we'll just flip the arguments and remember to `flip` them back later.

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar repstr char =
  (((. (repstr ++)) . (++)) <$> fst <*> tail . snd) . break (char ==)
```

And now we'll actually reduce `char`:

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar repstr =
  ((((. (repstr ++)) . (++)) <$> fst <*> tail . snd) .) . break . (==)
```

Now we need to rearrange the entire function to get `repstr` at the end. Start by turning `. break . (==)` into a section:

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar repstr =
  (. break . (==)) $ ((((. (repstr ++)) . (++)) <$> fst <*> tail . snd) .)
```

Unsection the second half:

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar repstr =
  (. break . (==)) $ (.) $ ((. (repstr ++)) . (++)) <$> fst <*> tail . snd
```

Section `<*> tail . snd`

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar repstr =
  (. break . (==)) $ (.) $ (<*> tail . snd) $ ((. (repstr ++)) . (++)) <$> fst
```

Section `<$> fst`:

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar repstr =
  (. break . (==)) $ (.) $ (<*> tail . snd) $ (<$> fst) $ (. (repstr ++)) . (++)
```

Section `. (++)`:

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar repstr =
  (. break . (==)) $ (.) $ (<*> tail . snd) $ (<$> fst) $ (. (++)) $ (. (repstr ++))
```

Unsection `(. (repstr ++))`:

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar repstr =
  (. break . (==)) $ (.) $ (<*> tail . snd) $ (<$> fst) $ (. (++)) $ flip (.) $ (repstr ++)
```

Unsection `(repstr ++)`:

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar repstr =
  (. break . (==)) $ (.) $ (<*> tail . snd) $ (<$> fst) $ (. (++)) $ flip (.) $ (++) repstr
```

Eta-reduce:

```
replaceChar :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replaceChar =
  (. break . (==)) . (.) . (<*> tail . snd) . (<$> fst) . (. (++)) . flip (.) . (++)
```

And `flip` to put the arguments back in the right order:

```
replaceChar :: Char -> String -> String -> String
replaceChar =
  flip $ (. break . (==)) . (.) . (<*> tail . snd) . (<$> fst) . (. (++)) . flip (.) . (++)
```

Et-voilà: a completely illegible pile of gibberish that magically does what you need for no reason comprehensible to humankind.

Comment: Am I blind, or does this not work for inputs where there are multiple occurences of the wildcard, e.g. `"foo***"`?

Comment: You're right. OP does not specify desired behavior of multiple occurrences. Though I probably could have inferred from the reference implementation. I'll leave this up though, since it does match the implementation of a number of `replace` functions. There's no way I'm going through that eta-reduction exercise again for a minor alteration. Which is exactly why something of this complexity should not be written point-free.

Comment: And I would need recursion and `fix` always gets me befuddled.

Comment: I really like your solution, as it shows how crazy you can go with *This has to be point-free what ever it takes*.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't completely agree with @Andrew Ray, that converting your version of the function into point-free style is not possible, I want to present another possibility.

We can replace the `if` clause with `bool` from `Data.Bool`. First of all we tackle the lambda clause (`\c -> if c==wildcard then sub else [c]`). To point-free our `replace` function, I added a `helper` first, that takes two additional arguments, the replacement string and a predicate, deciding which characters to keep and which to replace:

```
helper :: [b] -> (b -> Bool) -> b -> [b]
helper repl pred c = if pred c then repl else [c]
```

By using `bool` we get rid of the `if` clause. Note the reversed order of the `if` and `else` branches, that's because `bool` works the other way round.

```
helper repl pred c = bool [c] repl $ pred c
```

Since `c` is used twice in the body of `helper`, we can use the `Applicative` instance of functions to apply `c` to multiple functions using the `liftAN` functions. Although `repl` does not need `c`, we can turn it into a function that takes `c` by using `const`. Thus we use `liftA3` now:

```
helper repl pred c = liftA3 bool ((:[])) (const repl) pred $ c
```

Now we can easily chop of `c` and `pred`:

```
helper repl = liftA3 bool ((:[])) (const repl)
```

and by using function composition to replace (in general) `f (g x)` with `f . g $ x`, we can rewrite this to:

```
helper repl = liftA3 bool ((:[])) . const $ repl
```

Where, again, we can chop of `repl`:

```
helper = liftA3 bool ((:[])) . const
```

Now let's tackle the main function by putting our helper in there.

```
replace :: (Foldable t, Eq b) => b -> [b] -> t b -> [b]
replace wildcard sub = concatMap (helper sub (==wildcard))
```

Since we need `wildcard` and `sub` in a different order, we `flip` `helper`:

```
replace wildcard sub = concatMap ((flip helper) (==wildcard) sub)
```

To get `sub` out of the second term, we can prefix `(.)`:

```
replace wildcard sub = (.) concatMap ((flip helper) (==wildcard)) $ sub
```

where we can easily chop of `sub`:

```
replace wildcard = (.) concatMap ((flip helper) (==wildcard))
```

The third term can be rewritten with function composition:

```
replace wildcard = (.) concatMap ((flip helper) . (==) $ wildcard)
```

Now section the prefix `(.)`:

```
replace wildcard = (concatMap .) ((flip helper) . (==) $ wildcard)
```

Finally we can apply the `f (g x) = f . g $ x` pattern again:

```
replace wildcard = (concatMap .) . ((flip helper) . (==)) $ wildcard
```

where we can chop of `wildcard`. Replacing `helper` with our definition, we get:

```
replace = (concatMap .) . ((flip $ liftA3 bool ((:[])) . const) . (==))
```

Although this might be slightly more readable than @Andrew Ray's solution, I still strongly recommend you, not to force point-free style in such a way. The original was way more readable than this nonsense.

Comment: Somehow, I'd interpreted "not allowed to import external libraries" as "not allowed to import libraries", so I'd discounted `bool` since it's not in Prelude.

Comment: Oh I see, If this is not allowed, my answer does not fit the requirements. Although I think it's still worth it to show this alternative.